# Interactive / social app content and apple app aproval

Tags: iphone, ios

I am near to finish building my first app and some parts of my app are social which allows user to create and share content that has images and text.

I tried researching on interactive content and apple approval criteria but couldn't find anything. thus hoping someone could guide me a bit.

1) Do I have to make a picture approval process for the images uploaded by the users otherwise my app wouldn't be approved?

2) Do I have to filter for profanity in the text shared by users otherwise my app wouldn't be approved?

Comment: You will get a 17+ rating, but it will likely be approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you uploading them to firstly? If Facebook or Twitter using the social framework you don't need to do this.

Comment: my server, but there are other apps that do need approval for pictures.

Comment: It's probably less that they do need approval from Apple's guidelines and more like they want to add approval as an insurance if users start abusing their service, they can ban them etc. We created an app for an event that had a sharing photo service via our server and web services and Apple didn't have any issues.